# If $X$ is an infinite set, then $|X|=|F(X)|$, where $F(X)$ is the free group on $X$

Tags: group-theory, elementary-set-theory, free-groups, infinite-groups

I am struggling to prove that for an infinite set $|X|=|F(X)|$, where $F(X)$ is the free group on $X$.

I can see the obvious injection $X \to F(X)$ but struggling to see the converse.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Isn't every element in $F(X)$ obtained as a **finite product** of elements from $X$? (Don't need to consider inverse operation in obtaining the elements, since the inverse of elements all belong to $X.$ But even if we did for some reason, that would simply at most double the result.) So $|F(X)|$ is at most $|X| + 2\cdot |X| + 3 \cdot |X| + \cdots$ $({\aleph_0}$-many summands), which equals ${\aleph_0} \cdot |X| = |X| = \min\{\aleph_{0},\, |X|\} = |X|.$ In this computation I'm actually counting all **finite ordered sequences**, which is overkill by commutativity and other identities.

Comment: By the way, I don't have time to write out a more formal answer, especially one in which some kind of injection is explicitly defined, so anyone else is free to chime in.

Comment: It's not obvious, since it relies on the axiom of choice.

Comment: Correction to @DaveL.Renfro's first comment, the "min" should be "max".

Comment: Oops! $\;\;\;\;$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to assume that for an infinite set $X$, $|X|=|X\times X|$. But in fact, the assertion that this holds for any infinite set is equivalent to the Axiom of Choice, which is a [theorem of Tarski's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_theorem_about_choice); this is what Asaf notes in comments regarding how you need the Axiom of Choice to establish this.

From that assumption it is clear that for every positive integer $n$, $|X^n|=|X|$.

Now, the elements of $F(X)$ are reduced finite sequences of elements of $X$ and their formal inverses (no element appears next to its formal inverse); there are $2|X|=|X|$ one-letter words (the factor of $2$ to account for formal inverses). There are at most $2|X|\times 2|X| = |X|^2 = |X|$ two-letter reduced words (because some combinations will include cancellations). Omitting the factors of $2$ from here on, since they don't matter, there are at most $|X|^3=|X|$ three-letter reduced worlds; etc. For each $n$, there are at most $|X|^n = |X|$ $n$-letter reduced words, since $X$ is infinite. Thus, $F(X)$ contains at most this many elements:
$$|X| + |X|^2 + |X|^3 + \cdots = \aleph_0|X| = \max\{\aleph_0,|X|\} = |X|,$$
because $X$ is infinite, so $\aleph_0\leq |X|$.

Thus, $|F(X)|\leq |X|$, and applying Cantor-Bernstein you can conclude that $|F(X)|=|X|$.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed that. Thanks for the update.

Comment: @freakish: It's a good point, and I thought about it while writing and then didn't say anything explicit, so thanks for bringing it up.

Comment: Thank you very much! Makes sense :)